# OpenOfficeException: connection failed: socket

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, openoffice.org

I have to write a simple service to convert any file to pdf. (I started with rtf to pdf). So, I wrote a service that listens to openoffice. The dockerfile for openoffice:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

EXPOSE 8100

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV OPENOFFICEVERSION 4.1.1
ENV OPENOFFICEPACKAGE Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.1_Linux_x86-64_install-deb_en-US.tar.gz


RUN useradd -m openoffice; \
    apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y  wget \
                    openjdk-7-jre; \
     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN wget -q 
http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/openofficeorg.mirror/$OPENOFFICEVERSION/binaries/en-US/$OPENOFFICEPACKAGE -O /tmp/$OPENOFFICEPACKAGE; \
     mkdir /tmp/OpenOffice; \
     tar -xzf /tmp/$OPENOFFICEPACKAGE -C /tmp/OpenOffice; \
     dpkg -i /tmp/OpenOffice/en-US/DEBS/*.deb; \
     dpkg -i /tmp/OpenOffice/en-US/DEBS/desktop-integration/*.deb; \
     rm -rf /tmp/$OPENOFFICEPACKAGE; \
     rm -rf /tmp/OpenOffice
 RUN apt update
 RUN apt-get install -y libxt6
 RUN apt-get install -y libxrender1

 CMD openoffice4 --headless --nologo --nofirststartwizard  
       --accept="socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=8100;urp"
```

The service in a docker-compose file I named openoffice as product-service

My java method doing the conversion:

```
import com.documents4j.api.DocumentType;
import com.documents4j.api.IConverter;
import com.documents4j.job.LocalConverter;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.net.ConnectException;
import java.nio.file.Files;

import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import com.model.*;
import com.s3.S3Credentials;
import com.s3.S3Manager;
import com.artofsolving.jodconverter.DocumentConverter;
import com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.connection.OpenOfficeConnection;
import com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.connection.SocketOpenOfficeConnection;
import com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.converter.OpenOfficeDocumentConverter;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
import com.itextpdf.text.Font;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.tutego.jrtf.Rtf;
import static com.tutego.jrtf.RtfPara.p;



@RestController
public class RtfController {
    S3Credentials s3cred;
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RtfController.class);

    @Autowired
    private Template template;

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public String helloWorld() {
        return "hello world!111";
    }

    public static boolean convertToPDF53() throws ConnectException{
         File inputFile = new File("out2.rtf");
         File outputFile = new File("out.pdf");
         OpenOfficeConnection connection = new SocketOpenOfficeConnection("http://product-service", 8100);
         connection.connect();
         DocumentConverter converter = new OpenOfficeDocumentConverter(connection);
         converter.convert(inputFile, outputFile);
         connection.disconnect();
         return true;
    }

}
```

From my main class I call RtfController.convertToPDF53() to do the conversion. I also created a dockerfile for own service and it runs on port 8080. So, to connect those 2 services I used docker-compose. I named an image for openoffice as t123 and an image for my own service is called t5

Here is my docker compose

```
version: '3'

services:
  product-service:
    image: t123:latest
    volumes:
      - ./t1
    ports:
      - 8100:8100
  web:
    image: t5:latest
    volumes:
      - ./abs-rtf/src
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - product-service
```

It starts builds successfully both containers but for some reason, it fails

> Attaching to 2bcb4c23fbf7_abs1_product-service_1, abs1_web_1 web_1
>   |
>   com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.connection.OpenOfficeException:
>   connection failed:
>   socket,host=http://product-service,port=8100,tcpNoDelay=1 web_1
>   |     at
>   com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.connection.AbstractOpenOfficeConnection.connect(AbstractOpenOfficeConnection.java:81)
>   web_1              |  at
>   com.absco.controller.RtfController.convertToPDF53(RtfController.java:275)
>   web_1              |  at
>   com.AbsRtfApplication.main(AbsRtfApplication.java:17) web_1
>   |     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) web_1              |  at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   web_1              |  at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   web_1              |  at
>   java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) web_1
>   |     at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:47)
>   web_1              |  at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:86)
>   web_1              |  at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
>   web_1              |  at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
>   web_1              | Caused by:
>   com.sun.star.connection.ConnectionSetupException:
>   java.net.UnknownHostException: http://product-service: Name or service
>   not known web_1              |    at
>   com.sun.star.lib.connections.socket.socketConnector.connect(socketConnector.java:162)
>   web_1              |  at
>   com.sun.star.comp.connections.Connector.connect(Connector.java:146)
>   web_1              |  at
>   com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.connection.AbstractOpenOfficeConnection.connect(AbstractOpenOfficeConnection.java:65)
>   web_1              |  ... 10 more

As I understand, my service cannot reach http://product-service I tried to do through localhost and mistake is similar

> java.net.ConnectException: connection failed:
>   socket,host=localhost,port=8100,tcpNoDelay=1:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

How to solve this problem? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Services running inside Docker containers always need to listen on the magic “all interfaces” IPv4 address 0.0.0.0.  When you start up with `host=127.0.0.1` that setting makes the service unreachable from outside the container.

Comment: Thanks. I changed but it still doesn't work